# Value of $({b\over a}+{a\over b})^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive real numbers such that $${1\over a}-{1\over b}-{1\over a+b}=0. $$
>   Find the value of $({b\over a}+{a\over b})^2$.

I tried to get the relationship between $a$ and $b$ or any other form which could help in this problem but I couldn't.

Please help me

Comment: Please use MathJax to display the equations.

Comment: How to use  mathjax

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Now that we can properly interpret the question, the next step is: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to take the lcm and find the relationship

Comment: $\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{a+b}$ so $\frac{b-a}{ab}=\frac{1}{a+b}$ cross multiplying gives $b^2-a^2-ab$ so the difference between the squares equals their product.

Comment: Yes I already got it but how to do further

Comment: Please make the title more informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a+b}=0 \iff b^2-a^2=ab,$$
$$(b^2+a^2)^2 = (b^2-a^2)^2+4a^2b^2=5a^2b^2.$$
Can you continue from here?